# "Undefined label" error in java when using labeled break

Tags: java, label, break

I'm trying to analyse a java code and see what it does, but in the "break label" line it gives the "Undefined label" error. from my understanding java unlike c# allows breaking into a scope outside of the current scope. isn't that right?

```
if (conditions) {
  // some code
  if (conditions) {
    break label;
  }
  // some code
}

for (;;) {
  if (conditions) {
    // some code
  }
  // some code
  break;
  label: 
  // some code
}
```

Comment: Good grief. What horrendous-looking code. If it gives a compiler error, it doesn't "do" anything, so there's no point in analyzing it.

Comment: @AndyTurner its decompiled , I guess its an error on the side of decompiler.

Comment: If your decompiler produces uncompilable code, is it really worth using?

Comment: dex2jar is the only choice when it comes to decompiling apk..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, you are trying to use `break label;` as though it were similar to the `goto label;` syntax in C/C++. This is not how it works in Java.

in Java, the `break label;` syntax is applicable only when you are using nested loops and you need to break out from an inner loop to one of the outer loops in question.

For example:

```
outer: while(some condition) {
    inner: while(another condition) {
        innermost: while(yet another condition) {
            if(breaking_condition) {
                break inner;
            } else if (one more breaking condition) {
                break outer;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Refer this tutorial from Oracle:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: A `break` statement is not only usable within an enclosing iteration statement, i.e., `while`, `do`, and `for` statements. It's also usable within an enclosing `switch` statement.

Also, the break target, i.e., the labeled statement with the same label as used in the `break` statement, needs not be a `switch`, `while`, `do`, or `for` statement.

Check out [JLS 11 - 14.15. The break Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15).

Comment: Consider this program:

`class Break {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int i = 0, j = 0;

        a: if (true) {
            b: switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    c: switch (j) {
                        case 0:
                            System.out.println("Inside the inner switch");

                            <break_statement>
                    }

                    System.out.println("After the inner switch");
            }

            System.out.println("After the outer switch");
        }
    }
}
`

Comment: Output when `<break_statement>` is:
  1. `break a;`:
  `Inside the inner switch`
  
  2. `break b;`: 
  `Inside the inner switch
  After the outer switch`
  
  3.`break c;`:
  `Inside the inner switch
  After the inner switch
  After the outer switch`
  
  4. `break;`:
  `Inside the inner switch
  After the inner switch
  After the outer switch`